# On React, how do fix Error: <svg> attribute width: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected length, ""

Tags: reactjs, svg

```
<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 42 42" fill="none" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M11.8965 4.15234H27.1215C30.9516 6.86499 34.2912 10.2108 36.9967 14.046V37.4636H11.8965V4.15234Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
                        <path d="M11.8965 4.15234H27.1215C30.9516 6.86499 34.2912 10.2108 36.9967 14.046V37.4636H11.8965V4.15234Z" stroke="#C8C8C8" strokeWidth="0.25"/>
                        <path d="M27.1191 4.15234C30.9445 6.87152 34.2839 10.2163 36.997 14.046C36.095 13.1189 35.0013 12.4002 33.7925 11.9399C32.5837 11.4797 31.2889 11.2892 29.9988 11.3816C30.1827 10.0306 30.0143 8.65494 29.5097 7.38825C29.0052 6.12156 28.1816 5.00685 27.1191 4.15234Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
                        <path d="M27.1191 4.15234C30.9445 6.87152 34.2839 10.2163 36.997 14.046C36.095 13.1189 35.0013 12.4002 33.7925 11.9399C32.5837 11.4797 31.2889 11.2892 29.9988 11.3816C30.1827 10.0306 30.0143 8.65494 29.5097 7.38825C29.0052 6.12156 28.1816 5.00685 27.1191 4.15234V4.15234Z" stroke="#C8C8C8" strokeWidth="0.25"/>
                        <path d="M7.00732 8.52344H25.5136V12.0672H7.00732V8.52344Z" stroke="#C8C8C8" strokeWidth="2"/>
                        <path d="M20.7621 26.0611C21.3737 24.8615 22.0746 23.5109 22.6258 22.1538L22.8463 21.6183C22.1192 18.8516 21.6834 16.6308 22.0733 15.1949C22.155 15.0016 22.296 14.8392 22.476 14.7312C22.656 14.6231 22.8656 14.575 23.0747 14.5938H23.4081C24.0433 14.5846 24.3413 15.3918 24.3754 15.7055C24.3802 16.1809 24.3179 16.6546 24.1903 17.1125C24.2215 16.6256 24.1495 16.1377 23.979 15.6806C23.7165 15.1044 23.4658 14.7618 23.2414 14.7054C23.1615 14.7701 23.0967 14.8513 23.0513 14.9436C23.006 15.0358 22.9813 15.1368 22.9789 15.2396C22.9123 15.647 22.8785 16.0592 22.8778 16.472C22.9088 17.6858 23.0999 18.8901 23.4461 20.0538C23.517 19.8491 23.5774 19.6522 23.6299 19.4671C23.7073 19.1758 24.1982 17.2477 24.1982 17.2477C24.1982 17.2477 24.0748 19.8149 23.9016 20.5906C23.8648 20.7547 23.8241 20.9174 23.7808 21.0828C24.3619 22.7491 25.3263 24.2556 26.5961 25.481C27.0949 25.9137 27.6409 26.2888 28.2236 26.5993C29.3171 26.4343 30.4214 26.3514 31.5272 26.3512C32.4142 26.2617 33.3063 26.461 34.0708 26.9195C34.2393 27.0895 34.3389 27.3157 34.3504 27.5548C34.3447 27.6796 34.3267 27.8036 34.2966 27.9249C34.3097 27.8579 34.3097 27.5311 33.3056 27.2083C31.9691 26.954 30.5984 26.9349 29.2553 27.1518C31.3106 28.1572 33.3148 28.6573 33.9488 28.358C34.0826 28.2686 34.1991 28.1556 34.2926 28.0246C34.2486 28.2419 34.1844 28.4545 34.101 28.6599C33.9745 28.8206 33.8018 28.9387 33.6062 28.9985C32.6034 29.261 29.9942 28.6468 27.7196 27.3474C25.1516 27.7416 22.6199 28.3434 20.1491 29.1468C17.9507 33.0003 16.2969 34.7696 14.9529 34.0963L14.4581 33.8482C14.3679 33.7754 14.3019 33.677 14.2689 33.5659C14.2358 33.4548 14.2373 33.3363 14.2731 33.2261C14.4293 32.4596 15.3913 31.3033 17.3233 30.1496C17.5307 30.0183 18.4573 29.534 18.4573 29.534C18.4573 29.534 17.7709 30.1981 17.6108 30.3281C16.0686 31.592 14.9306 33.1814 14.9582 33.7983V33.8521C16.2707 33.6658 18.2329 30.9988 20.7581 26.0572L20.7621 26.0611ZM21.5588 26.4667C21.1627 27.2075 20.7576 27.9435 20.3434 28.6743C22.4489 27.8305 24.6376 27.2111 26.8731 26.8263C26.5843 26.6277 26.3053 26.4153 26.037 26.1898C24.8843 25.1956 23.9465 23.9768 23.2808 22.6079C22.794 23.9324 22.2164 25.2217 21.5522 26.4667" fill="#F91D0A"/>
                        <path d="M4.92188 6.51953H27.5809V14.136H4.92188V6.51953Z" fill="url(#paint2_linear)"/>
                        <path d="M28.0129 14.5924H4.51123V6.0625H28.0129V14.5924ZM27.1689 6.90775H5.35648V13.7446H27.1689V6.90775Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"/>
                        <path d="M10.8442 7.63967H12.4927C12.7009 7.62634 12.9095 7.65828 13.1041 7.73328C13.2987 7.80827 13.4748 7.92455 13.6202 8.07411C13.9028 8.41916 14.0436 8.85885 14.0139 9.30392C14.0436 9.75099 13.9029 10.1927 13.6202 10.5403C13.4744 10.6891 13.2982 10.8047 13.1036 10.879C12.909 10.9533 12.7006 10.9846 12.4927 10.9708H11.8365V12.7414H10.8442V7.63967ZM11.8378 8.59254V10.0179H12.3877C12.4713 10.0227 12.5548 10.0085 12.632 9.97647C12.7093 9.94442 12.7784 9.89533 12.834 9.83286C12.9465 9.68179 13.0023 9.49592 12.9915 9.30786C13.0035 9.11964 12.9477 8.93335 12.834 8.78286C12.7784 8.72031 12.7094 8.67116 12.6321 8.63911C12.5548 8.60706 12.4713 8.59293 12.3877 8.59779H11.8378V8.59254ZM15.7084 8.63848V11.7478H16.0641C16.239 11.7595 16.4142 11.73 16.5756 11.6616C16.737 11.5932 16.88 11.4878 16.9933 11.354C17.2302 11.015 17.3441 10.6052 17.3162 10.1925C17.3441 9.78224 17.2311 9.37475 16.9959 9.03748C16.8821 8.90372 16.7385 8.79844 16.5767 8.73007C16.4149 8.6617 16.2393 8.63214 16.0641 8.64373H15.7084V8.63848ZM14.7148 7.64886H15.7648C16.2034 7.62651 16.6426 7.68024 17.0629 7.80767C17.3563 7.92185 17.6118 8.11601 17.8005 8.36811C17.9848 8.60528 18.1216 8.87579 18.2034 9.16479C18.2953 9.49769 18.3395 9.84193 18.3347 10.1872C18.3395 10.5356 18.2953 10.8828 18.2034 11.2189C18.1216 11.5079 17.9848 11.7784 17.8005 12.0155C17.6095 12.2684 17.3524 12.4637 17.0576 12.5799C16.6364 12.7078 16.1966 12.7632 15.7569 12.744H14.7069V7.63967L14.7148 7.64886ZM19.0933 7.63967H21.7879V8.63454H20.0947V9.58348H21.6816V10.5784H20.0947V12.7414H19.1012V7.63967" fill="#FFF9F9"/>
                        <defs>
                        <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="19.2239" y1="30.2469" x2="28.5086" y2="13.4663" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop stopColor="white"/>
                        <stop offset="1" stopColor="#E1E1E1"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="30.9188" y1="10.1492" x2="32.3468" y2="8.83272" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop stopColor="white"/>
                        <stop offset="1" stopColor="#C8C8C8"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient id="paint2_linear" x1="18.4524" y1="17.1022" x2="14.0503" y2="3.55328" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop offset="0.127" stopColor="#8A0000"/>
                        <stop offset="0.244" stopColor="#900000" stopOpacity="0.999"/>
                        <stop offset="0.398" stopColor="#A00000" stopOpacity="0.999"/>
                        <stop offset="0.573" stopColor="#BC0000" stopOpacity="0.998"/>
                        <stop offset="0.761" stopColor="#E20000" stopOpacity="0.997"/>
                        <stop offset="0.867" stopColor="#FA0000" stopOpacity="0.996"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="18.6377" y1="17.6388" x2="13.8877" y2="3.01619" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop offset="0.315" stopColor="#5E0000"/>
                        <stop offset="0.444" stopColor="#830000" stopOpacity="0.999"/>
                        <stop offset="0.618" stopColor="#AE0000" stopOpacity="0.998"/>
                        <stop offset="0.775" stopColor="#CD0000" stopOpacity="0.997"/>
                        <stop offset="0.908" stopColor="#E00000" stopOpacity="0.996"/>
                        <stop offset="1" stopColor="#E70000" stopOpacity="0.996"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                    </svg>
```

After I'd changed attributes to camel cases, I go this error, Any help? I'm not sure what react is complaining about or what i need to change.
On React, how do fix  Error:  attribute width: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected length

Comment: Please post your React code

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I posted the wrong Svg and I just noticed 
because of your comment, I'd many on the page. Fortunately, I've seen where the errors is coming from.  The width and height  attribute had no value, something like  this
 " width= ' '  "  . It should be with a value or shouldn't be there at all